# Setting up Parent-Child Actor in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, actor

I just started working on Play Framework + Akka. I have one Parent Actor and one child Actor(in future it can exceed). I am making an Api call from a controller and expecting a response from child actor.

NotificationController:

```
@Singleton
public class NotificationController extends Controller{
    final ActorRef commActor;

    @Inject
    public NotificationController(ActorSystem system) {
        commActor = system.actorOf(CommActor.props, "comm-actor");
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> communicate(int isDirect, int mode, int messageId){
        return FutureConverters.toJava(ask(commActor, 
               new CommActorProtocol.CA(isDirect, mode, messageId), 1000))
              .thenApply(response -> ok((String) response).as("application/json"));
    }
}
```

CommActor(Parent Actor)

```
public class CommActor extends UntypedActor {
    public static Props props = Props.create(CommActor.class);
    private ActorRef notificationActor;

    public CommActor(){
        notificationActor = this.getContext().actorOf(NotificationActor.props, "notification-actor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception { 
        notificationActor.tell(message, self());
}
```

NotificationActor (Child Actor):

```
public class NotificationActor extends UntypedActor{
    public static Props props = Props.create(NotificationActor.class);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        sender().tell("Hi from notification", self());
    }
}
```

Parent Actor is responding correctly, but when I replace it with Notification tell. I get exception; I am not able to figure it out where the thing is going wrong.

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[Completio
nException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://app
lication/user/comm-actor#1301952259]] after [1000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message
 of type "protocols.CommActorProtocol$CA".]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(
HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.
scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorH
andler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1
.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1
.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346
)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345
)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutExce
ption: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://application/user/comm-actor#1301952259]] a
fter [1000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "protocols.CommActorProtocol$C
A".
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source
)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown
Source)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConverter
sImpl.scala:21)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConverter
sImpl.scala:18)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1
(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://appl
ication/user/comm-actor#1301952259]] after [1000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message
of type "protocols.CommActorProtocol$CA".
        at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala
:604)
        at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Fu
ture.scala:601)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scal
a:109)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scal
a:599)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightAr
rayRevolverScheduler.scala:331)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightA
rrayRevolverScheduler.scala:282)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRev
olverScheduler.scala:286)
        at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolver
Scheduler.scala:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I think you need to pass on the sender of the the message (ie. the controller) to the child so that it can reply to the correct party. Right now you're passing the parent actor as the sender so the response from the child will never reach the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem. In case any one stuck with same problem. It was basically going to an infinite loop from CommActor to NotificationActor.

CommActor:

```
if (message instanceof CA) {
            int mode = ((CA) message).mode;
            this.originator = getContext().sender();
            switch(mode){
            case 1: //SMS
                 break;
             case 2: //Email
                 break;
             case 3: //Notification
                 notificationActor.tell(new NA((CA)message), getSelf());
                 break;
            }
        }
        else if (message instanceof Response) {
            originator.tell(((Response) message).getResponse(), getSelf());
        }
        else{
            unhandled(message);
        }
```

Where CA/NA are protocols for Notification/CommActor

NotificationActor:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof NA){
getSender().tell(new Response(response), getSelf());}}
```